# How to import methods from a file in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file which is under src/math2/add.py

**add.py:**

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Now I have a second file where I am trying to use that, which is operations.py.

**operations.py:**

```
import add

def operations(what, param1, param2):
    if(what == 'add'):
        return add(param1, param2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    operation('add', 9, 18)
```

But when I try running  `python3 operations.py`, I get an error `no module named 'add'`.
I have added an `__init__.py` file in the math folder, still I get this error.

This is my folder structure:

```
src/math2/__init__.py
src/math2/add.py
src/operations.py
```

I remember this used to work great with Python 2.7.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from build_job import add`?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it was a typo in my question... i corrected that... file name is add.py

Comment: `import .add` ?

Comment: I get invalid syntax error if I do import .add  @ma3oun

Comment: `from math.add import add` ? Also it is bad practice to name your functions as functions already present in python like `add`

Comment: could you please give this a try: `from math import add` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I get error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math.add'; 'math' is not a package`

Comment: from .math.add import add

Comment: Where are you running `operations.py` from?

Comment: @gmds I am running it from `src` directory

Comment: How about `from operator import add` instead of reinventing the wheel? Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

Comment: @DimaTisnek its just an example... my use case is i want to import from a file.

Comment: @undefined Your example should avoid using builtin names if your real code doesn't, because there are actual problems with doing so that can confuse the issue.

Comment: agree, sorry for that. @gmds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to point out that there is already a library called math in python environment. After you change the name of the directory to lets say math2, you can try the following:

To add the module you should use `from math2 import add` and it should work.

You can refer to [python docs on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) for more information.

Edit: You are referencing the `add` module as if it is a function in `operations.py`. You should either do `from math2.add import add` or you should call `add.add()` in the previous form.

Comment: i renamed it and tried, but now i get this error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: what did you rename it to? and where are you calling it?  can you update your question with it?

Comment: i renamed math folder to math2 and tried importing `from math2 import add`

Comment: try doing `add.add()` in operations or doing `from math2.add import add`

Answer (score 1):

you have misspelled method name in operations.py on last line.
it should be **operations('add', 9, 18)**

below is the modified operations.py which is working fine.

```
from math2.add import add

def operations(what, param1, param2):
    if(what == 'add'):
        a= add(param1, param2)
        print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    operations('add', 9, 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `PYTHONPATH` to your src folder

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/<src-path>
```

Then, use this import:

```py
from math.add import add
```

Comment: Don't set `PYTHONPATH`, instead rely on Python packages :)

Comment: Why should setting the PYTHONPATH help in this case? OP is running from the `src` directory.